# Optimization within Dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to find an optimization solution within a dataframe.  Choosing from three separate rows, I would like to find a solution that minimizes the formula:   result = (sum(column(b)) + sum(column(c)) / sum(column(a)))

```
> set.seed(1)
> a <- sample.int(10,size = 10)
> b <- sample.int(10,size = 10)
> c <- sample.int(10,size = 10)
> df_optimize <- data.frame(a,b,c)
> df_optimize
    a  b  c
1   9  3  5
2   4  1  9
3   7  5  1
4   1  8  6
5   2  2 10
6   5  6  7
7   3 10  2
8  10  9  4
9   6  4  3
10  8  7  8
> 
> objective_function <- function(x,y,z) {
+   p_1 <- x$a + y$a + z$a
+   p_2 <- x$b + y$b + z$b
+   p_3 <- x$c + y$c + z$c
+   result <- (p_2 + p_3) / p_1
+   return(result)
+ }
> 
> #example result outputs
> objective_function(df_optimize[1,],df_optimize[3,],df_optimize[5,])
[1] 1.444444
> #and
> objective_function(df_optimize[2,],df_optimize[4,],df_optimize[6,])
[1] 3.7
> 
> # Attempt to find combination that minimizes result
> optimize(interval = df_optimize[1:10,], f = objective_function)
Error in x$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: `optimize` is a one dimensional optimizer, you have 3 arguments to your objective function. `optimize` will pass `x` in `interval`, the other 2 arguments should go in the extra args part of the call, the *dots after `interval`*. Try putting print statements at the beginning of the objective function and see that `y` and `z` are missing. As for `x`, the source for your error, it's a scalar, `optimize` passes one value at a time.

Comment: See `optimr` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force, grid search solution.

```
inx <- 1:nrow(df_optimize)
arg_space <- expand.grid(inx, inx, inx)
i <- apply(arg_space, 1, \(x) any(x[1] == x[-1] | x[2] == x[3]))
arg_space <- arg_space[!i,]

res <- sapply(1:nrow(arg_space), \(i) {
  j1 <- arg_space[i, 1, drop = TRUE]
  j2 <- arg_space[i, 2, drop = TRUE]
  j3 <- arg_space[i, 3, drop = TRUE]
  objective_function(df_optimize[j1,],df_optimize[j2,],df_optimize[j3,])
})
i_opt <- which.min(res)

arg_space[i_opt, ]
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
#29    9    3    1

res[i_opt]
#[1] 0.9545455
```

---

## Edit

When scaling to more variables, make sure the column numbers are all different with

```
i <- apply(arg_space, 1, \(x) length(unique(x)) == length(x))
arg_space <- arg_space[i,]
```

Note that this extracts where the condition id `TRUE`, it uses `i` not `!i`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Now, I'm attempting to scale my formula and your grid search from three to four (or more) variables.  How would your grid search format change particularly `i <- apply(arg_space, 1, \(x) any(x[1] == x[-1] | x[2] == x[3]))`

Comment: By the way, would it be possible with a different optimizer.  I'm not restricted to `optimize`

Comment: @mpr122716o As for the `apply` loop, it checks the rows for all different entries, if you scale your formula you will need a way to do the same. As for optimizers, see the respective [Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

Comment: Thank you.  When scaling to 5 variables, does the apply loop become `i <- apply(arg_space, 1, \(x) any(x[1] == x[-1] | x[2] == x[3] | x[3] == x[4] | x[4] == x[5]))` ? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: @mpr122716o No, use the edit instead.